# Replacing lipo battery with a power supply

Tags: power-supply, amperage, lipo

For a project i'd like to power a brushless motor that works with esc and lipos but i need to replace the lipos with a power supply so the motor can run longer, i need 50v and need to be able to pull up to 100 amperes, got any ideas how to?

Comment: what's your average current, a few amps, or 50 amps?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `got any ideas how to?` ... vague question ... here is a vague answer ... yes ... design, or buy, a power supply that can source the required current at the required voltage

Comment: Genuine question: What answer other than eg "Use a 50V, 100A supply" are you wanting. || Telecom supplies at 50V and large amperage are available surplus. || Providing a supply that "tops up" a battery may be useful.

Comment: yeah i noticed it was kinda vague sorry, but i was wondering if such power supplies existed and where i could buy them. Its to build a wind tunnel with winds that goes up to 250KPH